# How to draw the following process diagram in LaTeX with figure references?

Tags: diagrams, flow-charts

I need to draw the following two process diagram in LaTeX with figure references. Now I input that as images, but it doesn't look good. I need some expert help to do it. There is no need to draw the blue box.

[image]

[image]

--------------According to Answer one ,I will take like this digrum -----------
[image]

are their any way to same size circles draw ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A place to start from using `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
    myboxcircle/.style={circle,draw=black,align=center},
}
\tikzset{
    myboxrounded/.style={rounded rectangle,draw=black,align=center},
}
\tikzset{
    myboxrectangle/.style={rectangle,draw=black,align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex] 
\node[myboxcircle] (CarrData) {Carrier\\ Data};
\node[myboxrounded] (EmbProc) [right =of CarrData] {Embedding\\ Process} edge [<-] (CarrData);
\node[myboxrectangle] (SteData) [right =of EmbProc] {Stego Data} edge [<-] (EmbProc);
\node[myboxcircle] (Keys) [above =of EmbProc] {Keys} edge [->] (EmbProc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
    myboxrounded/.style={rounded rectangle,draw=black,align=center},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[myboxrounded] (1) {1. text};
\node[myboxrounded] (6) [below left =of 1] {6. text};
\node[myboxrounded] (2) [below right =of 1] {2. text} ;
\node[myboxrounded] (3) [below=of 2] {3. text} edge (2);
\node[myboxrounded] (5) [below=of 6] {5. text} edge (6);
\node[myboxrounded] (4) [below right =of 5] {4. text};
\draw[to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}](1) edge (6);
\draw[to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}](1) edge (2);
\draw[to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}](4) edge (5);
\draw[to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}](4) edge (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I draw using above solution and it working, but i notice my circles not same size. are there any way to draw same size , circles ? (i will added drawed one below the quesion)

Comment: `\tikzset{
    myboxcircle/.style={circle,draw=black,align=center, minimum width=2cm},
}` or any other value of your choice that is large enough to fit the text.

Comment: thank you ,it is working perfectly.

Comment: can you please explain in second dirgrum nodes how to place, it looks like circuler ?

Comment: You can use `below left= of...` to for example place "6. Apply classification..."  with respect to "1. select...".

Answer (score 4):

Another way to draw your images with `tikz` packet:

- first image, using `chains` library and `join` macro:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}},
   box/.style = {draw, align=center, minimum height=7mm, 
                 on chain, join},
  boxr/.style = {box, rounded corners=3pt},
 ellip/.style = {ellipse, draw, minimum width=6em, minimum height=9mm, 
                 inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt,align=center},
 every join/.style = {arr}
                        ]
\node (n1) [ellip, on chain]  {Carrier\\ Data};
\node (n2) [boxr]   {Embedding\\ Process};
\node (n3) [box]    {Stego\\ Data};
\node (n4) [boxr]   {Exrtaction\\ Process};
\node (n5) [ellip, on chain, join]  {Extracted\\ Data};
%
\node (n6) [ellip, above=of n2] {Keys};
\node (n7) [ellip, above=of n4] {Keys};
\node (n8) [ellip, below=of n2] {Secret\\ data};
%
\draw[arr]  (n6) -- (n2);
\draw[arr]  (n7) -- (n4);
\draw[arr]  (n8) -- (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- second image, using ellipse shape for nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 5mm,
every node/.style = {ellipse, draw, text width=9em, 
                     inner xsep=-3pt, inner ysep=2pt,align=flush center},
                        ]
\node (n1)                      {1. Select the Suspected Object};
\node (n2) [below right =of n1] {2. Process Object if required};
\node (n3) [below=of n2]        {3. Apply Feature Extraction Process};
\node (n4) [below left=of n3]   {4. Select and design the Classifier};
\node (n5) [above left=of n4]   {5. Train the Classifier};
\node (n6) [above=of n5]        {6. Apply Classification};
%
\draw   (n1) -| (n2) -- (n3) |- (n4) -| (n5) -- (n6) |- (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thankyou very usefull answer